# Replace my operating system?

Tags: installation

I wanted to install Ubuntu on my new laptop, but I don't want to replace my operating system (Windows 7) that I just purchased. When I start the downloader from a CD Burned image, it acts as though I am replacing my new OS, despite the fact I was told it would give me an option to install it as a program. Will it replace it, or I am just being stupid?

Comment: Have you booted via a bootable usb? (live-usb)

Answer (score 0):

To install Ubuntu as a program, boot to Windows and use [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer).